# Notification about work or school account whenever I start windows

Tags: windows-10

Recently I have been getting the following notification whenever I log in to windows 10:

> There is a problem with your work or school account, click here to fix the problem

However, when I go there (or search for solutions online) I tend to end up with a step where I need to log into the specific account.

However, it is not my account but of someone who used my laptop recently, and who I don't want to bother with this.

I have full rights to my laptop, and am looking for a way to get rid of the notification.

Answer (score 0):

When going to "Settings">"Accounts" you should see your normal account in the overview under "Your info".

When going to "Access to work or school" you can select the offending account, and click "Disconnect", it will not require you to log in.

Comment: "Disconnect" is not an option in Windows 10 as of Jan 2021.